# Date labels intersecting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using [`Matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/) to plot data on [`Ubuntu 15.10`](http://www.ubuntu.com/). My y-axis has numeric values and my x-axis timestamps.

I'm having the problem that the date labels intersect with each other making it look bad. How do I increase the distance between the x-axis ticks/labels to be evenly spaced still? Since the automatic selection of ticks was bad I'm okay with manually setting the amount of date ticks. Any other solution is appreciated, too.

Besides, I'm using the following [`DateFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter):

```
formatter = DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y')
axis = plt.gca()
axis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following to your code:

```
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

Which automatically formats the x axis for you (rotates the labels to something like 30 degrees etc).

You can also manually set the amount of x ticks that show on your x-axis to avoid it getting crowded, by using the following:

```
max_xticks = 10
xloc = plt.MaxNLocator(max_xticks)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xloc)
```

I personally use both together as it makes the graph look much nicer when using dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the locations you want to be labeled:

```
axis.set_xticks(x[[0, int(len(x)/2), -1]])
```

where x would be your array of timestamps